# jQuery scroll-triggered fadein - I want the elements visible upon page load to fade in as well.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function here that relies on jQuery and does the following: when you scroll down the page, the elements that appear entirely in the browser window, will get faded in. It works great, but the problem is that if you refresh the page, the elements that are immediately visible in the window (without needing to scroll) will not become visible unless you give the scroll a little nudge.

Here's my current script :

```
    // The unhide function

/* Every time the window is scrolled .. */
$(window).scroll( function(){

    /* Look for the location of each desired element */
    $('.hideme').each( function(i){

        var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        /* If the object is completely visible in the browser window, fade it in */
        if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

            $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},800);

        }

    }); 

});
```

My css

```
.hideme {
opacity: 0;
}
```

What do I need to add to the script to make the elements that are immediately visible upon page load, fade in as well?

Comment: Are you not hiding back the elements if they are not completely visible again? I'm asking because you can put this code in a function and call it from load too but this will not reveal the elements that are already revealed. Just the visible ones in the screen so if an element is like half seen in the browser it's gonan be hidden even if you do it on load too [DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/X8jhZ/4/show/)